# Combine two .txt files (output into one file)

Tags: python, windows, file-io

How to go about writing code that combines two text files that are on my laptop. Join them together for a single file output. Are the files meant to be opened first in 'r' mode? with combining the files, are there different ways files can be combined or is it just straight forward. ( meaning can the combination of the files be edited). Is it possible for you guys to give me a starting point into writing this code. Maybe abit of information im missing.

Comment: How about you tell us what you are trying to do? Combining files is just a programming task, Python can handle this any way you like but as it stands your question is too broad and vague to be answered; see the [FAQ#dontask].

Comment: You mean you want to implement the `cat` utility in Python?

Comment: its simple, I have two .txt files. I want to join them together to create one output file. what other information do you need . i just want a ccode to be able to do this or some sort of information how writing a python code on doing it would work

Comment: The question was closed since you didn't give any examples or show code you have created to try and solve this.

Comment: even opening the .txt files hasn't been working

Comment: Im only learning about python , so I was afraid my code would be too "noob"

Answer (score 2):

you can use `open()`

```
try:
    with open("path of 1st file") as fone, open("path of 2nd file") as ftwo,\
       open("path of output file","w")as fout:
        for line in fone:
            fout.write(line)
        for line in ftwo:
            fout.write(line)

except IOError:
    print "Some Problem occured"
```

By default open opens a file in `"r"` (read mode). For writing to a file use `"w"` for appending use `"a"`

Answer (score 1):

Variation of @BhavishAgarwal's solution

```
with open('data1.txt') as f1, open('data2.txt') as f2, \
     open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(f1)
    fout.writelines(f2)
```

However in the case of the first file **not** ending in a newline (`'\n'`) this may/may not produce the desired result (probably not). In this case I would go with @BhavishAgarwal's solution again with a smaller change.

```
with open("path of 1st file") as fone, open("path of 2nd file") as ftwo,\
   open("path of output file","w")as fout:
    for line in fone:
        fout.write(line)
    if not line.endswith('\n'): # checks if last line had a newline
        fout.write('\n')
    for line in ftwo:
        fout.write(line)
```